# Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage (VirtualHost)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

HOST
127.0.0.1   yourebazar.local

httpd-vhosts.conf
NameVirtualHost *:80

    ServerName yourebazar.local:80
    DocumentRoot "d:\web\yourebazar"
    ErrorLog error_log
    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all

Restart Apache
typing - http://yourebazar.local
For a day of debugging, still this message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

but if I go to my `http://localhost` I saw my http://yourebazar.local site
which I configure my DocumentRoot in my httpd.conf like this - 
DocumentRoot "D:\web\yourebazar"

Any solution???

Comment: Your question can use a bit of rephrasing. Can you state facts rather than describing what you tried to do?